# Installing a printer with user in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am trying to automate a network printer installation. Each user has an ID which you have to give while installing the printer manually.

I currently have this form:

[image: form]

This is as far as I can get.

```
string ID = InputText.Text;
string strCmdText;


 strCmdText = "rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /m 'Apple Color LW 12/660 PS' /h 'Intel' /v 'Windows 10' /f %windir%\\inf\ntprint.inf /u rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if / b 'Apple Postscript Driver' / f '%windir%\\inf\ntprint.inf' / r 'lpt1:' / m 'Apple Color LW 12/660 PS'";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

It doesn't work, though. I am not sure I can enter my ID either.

I have no idea how to keep going. This is the dialog that I get when I install the printer manually. The password should be empty, I only need the username:

[image: enter password]

Any ideas?

Comment: do you get an error at the initialization of `strCmdText` ?

Comment: @MongZhu Sorry I copied it as pseudo-code. I added the actual string.